# in jsp, is HttpServletRequest mutable throught out all pages? (commons fileupload issue)

Tags: java, jsp, apache-commons-fileupload

when setting a file size limit on commons fileupload (diskfileupload class) to for example 10MB, when uploading a file that is more than 10MB, diskfileupload will throw a **sizelimitexceededexception**, with this I had a response.redirect("previous webpage") on the catch exception like the ff:

```
try{
 DiskFileUpload dfu = new DiskFileUpload();
 dfu.setSizeThreshold(4096);                
 dfu.setSizeMax(10 * 1024 * 1024);       
 dfu.setRepositoryPath(tempDir);  
 // get form values here after parse
 java.util.List formItems = dfu.parseRequest(request);

 ... some form params (shorten code)
 String userName = formItems.get("userName");
 if(userName.isEmpty()){
   response.redirect("/addUser?error=username cannot be empty");
 }
}catch(Exception e){
 if(e.toString().contains("SizeLimitExceededException")){
   response.redirect("/addUser?error=cannot upload more than 10MB file sise");
 } else {
   throw e;
 }
}
```

the problem is, when I am not uploading anything, just response redirect to to the addUser page when userName is empty, I can still get the old values of other field and show the error message, but when I upload a file that exceed the 10MB limit, when redirect back to addUser, all the old values are gone, and sometimes i see the content header is missing error.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *Unrelated:* Use `catch (SizeLimitExceededException e)` instead of that `toString().contains()` logic. You should take this opportunity to read more about exception handling.

Comment: What does *"I can still get the old values of other field"* mean? What other field? --- What does *"sometimes i see the content header is missing error"* mean? The error is in a query string, not a header. --- FYI: `/addUser?error=username cannot be empty` is a malformed URL. The error message needs to be URL encoded. Same for the other error *(where you misspelled `size`)*.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: Every request gets a different instance of `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: hi, sorry for the messy code, as i just shortened it (in a hurry), but was able to solve by just parsing the request using the diskfileupload without size limitation first to get the request form data, and then reparse it again, this time with the size limitation check to throw the sizelimitexceeded exception, that way i still have the form data to be used when redirected back to the previous page. since I need to retain the previously entered data by user.